# EditText disappears after closing expandedView

Tags: android

The problem I am having is the text that I type in the expanded view, is not being saved. The moment I close one group to open another, all the values saved in the first disappear. Can anyone advise me what to do so it can be saved not just for when I open the expandedView but also for when I restart it or resume it. I'm not sure how to use the onResume and onRestart functions. Thanks

I am attaching the code as well:

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    private int counter;
    SharedPreferences getPrefs;
    private Context context;
    String[] parent= new String [4];
    String[][] child= new String [4][4];
    String [][] weights= new String [4][4];

    boolean KU=false;
    boolean MC=false;
    boolean TI=false;
    boolean C=false;
    boolean allEdited=false;

    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    EditText et3;
    EditText et4;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        counter++;

        if (!allEdited)
        {
            et1= new EditText (context);
            et2= new EditText (context);
            et3= new EditText (context);
            et4= new EditText (context);

            child[groupPosition][0]=et1.getText().toString();       
            child[groupPosition][1]=et2.getText().toString();
            child[groupPosition][2]=et3.getText().toString();
            child[groupPosition][3]=et4.getText().toString();
        }

        if(!KU)
        {
            et1.setText(child[groupPosition][childPosition]);
            et1.setPadding(50, 10, 10, 10);
            et1.setTextSize(15);
            et1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            et1.setFocusable(true);
            et1.setInputType(0x00000002);
            weights[groupPosition][0]=(et1.getText().toString());

        }
        if (!et1.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            KU=true;
        }
        if(KU)
        {
            et1.setText(weights[groupPosition][0]);
            et1.setFreezesText(true);
        }

        if (!MC)
        {
            et2.setText(child[groupPosition][childPosition]);
            et2.setPadding(50, 10, 10, 10);
            et2.setTextSize(15);
            et2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            et2.setFocusable(true);
            et2.setInputType(0x00000002);
            weights[groupPosition][1]=(et2.getText().toString());
        }
        else if (!et2.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            MC=true;
        }
        weights[groupPosition][1]=(et2.getText().toString());

        if(MC)
        {
            et1.setText(weights[groupPosition][1]);
        }


        if (!TI)
        {
            et3.setText(child[groupPosition][childPosition]);
            et3.setPadding(50, 10, 10, 10);
            et3.setTextSize(15);
            et3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            et3.setFocusable(true);
            et3.setInputType(0x00000002);
            weights[groupPosition][2]=(et3.getText().toString());
        }

        else if (!et3.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            TI=true;
        }
        weights[groupPosition][2]=(et3.getText().toString());

        if(TI)
        {
            et3.setText(weights[groupPosition][2]);
        }

        if (!C)
        {
            et4.setText(child[groupPosition][childPosition]);
            et4.setPadding(50, 10, 10, 10);
            et4.setTextSize(15);
            et4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            et4.setFocusable(true);
            et4.setInputType(0x00000002);
            weights[groupPosition][3]=(et4.getText().toString());
        }

        else if (!et4.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            C=true;
        }
        weights[groupPosition][3]=(et1.getText().toString());

        if(C)
        {
            et4.setText(weights[groupPosition][3]);
        }


        if (KU && MC && TI && C)
        {
            allEdited=true;
        }

        if (counter==1)
            return et1;
        else if (counter==2)
            return et2;
        else if (counter==3)
            return et3;
        else if (counter==4)
            return et4;
        else
            counter=0; return et1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return child[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {
        return parent.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        TextView tv= new TextView (context);
        this.parent[groupPosition]=tv.getText().toString();

        getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String allCourses= getPrefs.getString("allClasses", "Please enter your course code");

        String[] courses= allCourses.split(",");

        for (int i=0;i<courses.length;i++)
        {
            this.parent[i]=courses[i];
        }
        tv.setText(this.parent[groupPosition]);
        tv.setPadding(50, 10, 10, 10);
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        return tv;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kapil said you can use list to store the values but those values will be destroyed once the activity is destroyed. If you want a permanent storage i.e. the values should remain even if you restart the app the should use **Shared Preferences** or **SQLite Database**.

Comment: I have tried implementing the SQLite Database, but I'm not sure if I did it properly. And the problem still persists. Please advise me

Comment: Or is it possible so save data in the Shared Preferences and make it not visible in the preferences

Comment: You are updating your String arrays eg. child[groupPosition][0] using `et1.getText().toString();` which onResume will be null thus there is no value. You need to assign values to String arrays using SQLite database or sharedPreference. This way they will show the saved data. And some FYI, always upvote the answers that helped you. This will encourage users to answer you.

Comment: thanks for the help. I cant upvote on an answer. Says I need more reputation.

Comment: @JavaNewbie No problem, I was just pointing you out. Upvote when you have required reputations. Also, if your question was solved then mark the answer to close it.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a Custom List Adapter, and whenever you type something in textview, have a list and assign it to the list for particular index(position)